# Firebase-server for Automated UI Tests in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, xcode-ui-testing

Has anyone had success using Urish' firebase-server for isolated UI Tests in XCode?

Resource for the Firebase-server component, which seems great btw (github link inside article)!

- https://www-staging.firebase.com/blog/2015-04-24-end-to-end-testing-firebase-server.html

## What I'm after

I want to be able to test scenarios like the below.

- I'm building an app that has some fairly advanced UI logic (for instance drag and drop) and I want a way to setup test data in firebase that I can run tests against and reset data to a previous stage.
- I'm also after testing logged in vs logged out use cases deterministically as the logged in use case sets up core data, etc. that I want to check is done correctly and doesn't overwrite data if logging out/in again, etc.
- I store data locally in core data that I sync w firebase via merging, etc. I want to test scenarios such as: A user updated firebase (via another device or web) whilst their primary device was offline and how the primary device will sync and update its core data objects when app starts, etc.

My general approach is that in my unit tests I can mock out firebase connections, etc. but with my UI Tests I want to test more 'end to end' scenarios - preferably only mocking out network/etc.

## What' I've done

I spotted Urish' firebase server [https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/04/end-to-end-testing-with-firebase-server_16.html:here] so I installed it via node npm

1. ensured I had `homebrew` installed
2. installed `node` via homebrew
3. added entries to my hosts file for tests (I used `127.0.0.1 localhost`)
4. I updated the `DATABASE_URL` in `GoogleService-Info.plist` to `ws://localhost:5000`
5. I had test data stored in firebase so I exported this to `TestData/4Projects3Levels.json`
6. Started firebase server in new terminal (my env is MAC) `node_modules/.bin/firebase-server -f TestData/4Projects3Levels.json`

Now I run the app I get the below error. Seems the app can't connect to the database in Firebase. What could I do wrong?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'No Firebase database specified.', reason: 'No Firebase database found for input: '
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a654b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109ca4141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a6bd625 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Nasta iOS                           0x0000000108202a82 +[FUtilities parseUrl:] + 791
    4   Nasta iOS                           0x000000010822e896 +[FIRDatabase databaseForApp:] + 342
    5   Nasta iOS                           0x000000010822e720 +[FIRDatabase database] + 102
    6   Nasta iOS                           0x000000010813e31d _TFIZvV9Nasta_iOS14InjectorMapper23firebaseDBRootReferenceFT_CSo20FIRDatabaseReferenceiU_FT_S1_ + 61
    7   Nasta iOS                           0x000000010812006a _TFE9Nasta_iOSPS_31FirebaseRootDBReferenceInjectedg23firebaseDBRootReferenceCSo20FIRDatabaseReference + 58
    8   Nasta iOS                           0x0000000108120117 _TFC9Nasta_iOS13FirebaseStorecfT_S0_ + 103
```